# Front end editing in custom joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1, joomla-component, joomla-module

i want to write a module which shows a menu for a restaurant.
I don't want that my customer needs to do anything in the backend.

If the User is logged in, every Menu point should have an edit button.
If it's clicked, a little div pops up where the menu point can be edited.

I'm faily new to joomla extension dev. But i do know php/js/ajax stuff.

Can anyone point me into the right direction. Is this even possible with just a module?
Has anybody an example where this technique is used?

I'm using joomla 3.1.

Best regards. Maik

Comment: check this out http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial‎

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a module for that? I guess you are talking about a component. If yes let us know if so then we can provide you the starting point...

Comment: yeah i guess i have to make a component

Comment: To save yourself major effort, you could create an article for each menu which **can** be edited via the frontend.